Custom Salesforce Open CTI adapter
I was tasked in creating a custom salesforce open cti adapter by my employer and I was wondering where the documentation for creating it was?
According to the Salesforce website, you could create the adapter via javascript and that's why my employer thought it would be possible.
I've been looking for the resources for a while now to no avail. I hope you guys can help me.
A guide or links for documentation about creating cti adapter.
